# Android: intent start activity error

Tags: android, webrtc

I am developing webrtc application and i am getting this error dont know why.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.shoaib.webrtc, PID: 20122 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.shoaib.webrtc/com.example.shoaib.w‌​ebrtc.MainActivity}: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.shoaib.webrtc/com.example.shoaib.webrtc.LoginAc‌​tivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml? 
at com.example.shoaib.webrtc.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity‌​.java:53)
```

This is happening when I try to start a new Activity via `startActivity(intent)`

```
   this.mSharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(Constants.SHARED_PREFS, 
    MODE_PRIVATE);
    if (!this.mSharedPreferences.contains(Constants.USER_NAME)){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent); //here i am getting error
        finish();
        return;
    }
```

Comment: Whats the error?

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.shoaib.webrtc, PID: 20122
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.shoaib.webrtc/com.example.shoaib.webrtc.MainActivity}: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.shoaib.webrtc/com.example.shoaib.webrtc.LoginActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
at com.example.shoaib.webrtc.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:53)

Comment: As the error states, declare that activity in your `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity> Ihave declared in this way is it right?

Comment: Hi Shoaib, were you able to resolve this? If so, post your answer and accept it. Otherwise, provide any additional information as edits to your main post.

Comment: Thank You problem has been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<activity android:name=".LoginActivity"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Mention your activity into your `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

**Below is the simplified code:**

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

<activity
    android:name=".LoginActivity"
</activity>
```